# Insert text into repeated tinyMCE elements

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, tinymce

I've been trying for a while now to find a decent way to insert and modify text in a tinyMCE textarea using jQuery with little success. Most of the answers that people provide are generally only being used for a single tinyMCE textarea, or by calling a tinyMCE field based off of an ID. This is all well and good but my project has me creating repeated fields dynamically on the page, which makes it difficult to get a specific tinyMCE element.

Before I implemented tinyMCE I was calling the repeated fields by their class in association with a parent div.

Ex:

```
     $(this).parents(".main-category").find(".js-description").val(product_data['description_' + $('#language').val()]);
```

The above code is run when I change the product via dropbox. "$(this)" being the dropbox, it then calls for the parent div and finds the description textarea where it would then input the correct default data (passed through from a controller) into the field.

the problem here is that when you initialize tinyMCE, the original text area is all but buried and become inaccessible with this method.

the tinyMCE site provides documentation for how to insert text into a tinyMCE field, but these only work when there's a single tinyMCE element on the page or when you are manually inserting the fields yourself.

```
    // Sets the HTML contents of the activeEditor editor
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html');

    // Sets the raw contents of the activeEditor editor
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html', {format : 'raw'});

    // Sets the content of a specific editor (my_editor in this example)
    tinyMCE.get('my_editor').setContent(data);

    // Sets the bbcode contents of the activeEditor editor if the bbcode plugin was added
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('[b]some[/b] html', {format : 'bbcode'});
```

Is there any way to convert any of these into something that I could use? Or is there some other method that I can use to insert information into the text areas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tinymce source element becomes inaccessible when the editor gets initialized. This is necessary because tinymce creates a new contenteditable iframe which is then used to edit text. The editor text gets writen back to the former textarea on several events.

You asked for a jQuery way to acces the tinymce editor content. This is possible.
The following example shows howto acces the editor body element, looks for a html element with class `.js-description` and resets its value.

```
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor || tinymce.get('my_editor_id') || tinymce.editors[0];
$(editor.getBody()).find(".js-description").val('new_val');
```

Comment: Tried this and sadly tinyMCE.activeEditor returns a null value, most likely due to the fact that activeEditor is null until I click on an editor, and I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getBody' of null" in my java console. Unfortunately I need to have these changes able occur on pageload without needing to select an active editor (as there can be more than 1 tinyMCE editor on a page at a time).

Comment: i used tinyMCE.activeEditor becasue you had listed this as the way you used it. activeEditor gets set when an editor has recieved a click from the user. see my updated answer